# What's the most correct way around this propel "Cannot redeclare function" error?

Tags: mysql, propel, redeclare

I have the following tables:

`user`, `logbook`, `user_logbook`

User logbook is a junction table (`isCrossRef="true"` in the schema.xml), containing `user_id` and `logbook_id` foreign keys.

I also wanted to remember the currently selected logbook for any given user, so I put a `current_logbook_id` in my `user` table also, and gave that a foreign key. However, in my `BaseUserQuery.php` file I get two `filterByLogbook()` functions.

I know that when you have two foreign keys to the same table, *from* the same table, you get functions like `getUserRelatedBySomething()` and `getUserRelatedBySomethingElse()`, but what is the best thing to do in this situation?

I can of course just remove the foreign key and just use the ID saved, or I suppose I could create a new junction table (though that doesn't seem correct). What is the best thing to do in this situation, in terms of *"doing the right thing"* in MySQL *and* Propel (hopefully I'll be able to do both!).

Comment: Unless there is a way already I'm not aware of, I suspect the right thing to do might be to fork Propel and add a clean way handling this situation.  Think of the good karma!

Comment: So are you fairly confident there's no possible way?

Comment: Actually I think there is - see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `schema.xml` add [phpName and refPhpName attributes](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/schema.html#foreignkey_element) to the foreign key in the user table definition:

```
  <table name="user" phpName="User">
    ...
    <foreign-key foreignTable="logbook" phpName="CurrentLogBook" refPhpName="CurrentLogBookUser">
      <reference local="current_logbook_id" foreign="id"/>
    </foreign-key>
    ...
  </table>
```

Then you should get `filterByCurrentLogBook()` and `filterByCurrentLogBookUser()` functions and no collisions.

Comment: Quick question though - is that supposed to make `$user->getCurrentLogbook()` available too? I don't see that :/

Comment: Yes, I have it in my test setup.